# How to apply css styling in flash AS3..?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

HI All,

I want to know how to style an anchor tag(eg: need to chnage color blue and I want to make it bold) in flash.

I created a flash widget that for rss feeds and Im not sure about how to add styles in it like css we using in dreamweaver.

Lets take a look at the script below, it is AS3..

what I want is..

1, I need to make that  a tag should be looking bold and paleblue color.

2, Need to add a grey border after description ends.

```
function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    var il:XMLList = xml.channel.item;
    for(var i:uint=0; i<il.length(); i++)
    {
    ta.htmlText="<a href='"+il.link.text()[0]+"'>"+il.title.text()[0]+"</a>"+"\<br />"+il.description.text()[0]+"\<br />"+"\<br /><hr />"+"<a href='"+il.link.text()[1]+"'>"+il.title.text()[1]+"</a>"+"\<br />"+il.description.text()[1]+"\<br />"+"\<br /><hr />"+"<a href='"+il.link.text()[2]+"'>"+il.title.text()[2]+"</a>"+"\<br />"+il.description.text()[2];
    addChild(ta);
               }
}
```

Looking for your REPLIES ..

Thanks in Advance!

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Stylesheet](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html) and apply it to your textfield like so:

```
var css:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
css.parseCSS('a { color: #99CCFF; font-weight: bold; }');
textField.styleSheet = css;
```

Flash only supports a subset of CSS rules for textfields, and this doesn't include borders so you'll probably need to draw your bottom border using the graphics API.

Comment: Hi Richard first of all thanks for the answer, but I gets an error report while I'm trying to apply this,


Are you sure is it apt for AS3..?


1119: Access of possibly undefined property styleSheet through a reference with static type fl.controls:TextArea.

Comment: Yes, it is valid AS3, but for a TextField rather than the TextArea component you seem to be using (or the version you are using). You could try applying the stylesheet to the textarea's textfield like this `ta.textField.styleSheet = css`. But, it probably won't work, so see this blog post for a possible solution: http://rantworld.blogs.com/flashlit/2006/08/styling_flex_te.html

Comment: Hi Richard, it makes another confusion after given ta.textField.styleSheet = css, suddenly scrollbar of the text area is disappeared, how to get that scrollbar back any idea..?

Comment: See the link I posted in my previous comment. I don't think you can apply a stylesheet to the version of the TextArea component that you are using.

Comment: Hi Richard, anyway I did it another way it really works for me, go through it Im sure it'll be a referance for you too..

http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/03/adding_css_supp.html

Comment: Did you know how to include package {  } with action script..? I get an error like this '1037: Packages cannot be nested.', I want to call package as inline not external .as file..

Comment: I don't think you can define packages or classes on the timeline if that is what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

```
you can use style sheet in flash textField, but not all properties are supported.
only below are supported:

    color
    display
    fontFamily
    fontSize 
    fontStyle
    fontWeight
    kerning
    leading
    letterSpacing
    marginLeft
    marginRight
    textAlign
    textDecoration
    textIndent

see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000292.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this a while ago to cover fonts specifically, but it has details in there on using CSS on elements within htmlText. I think it should help you, pay attention to the way the StyleSheet class works: http://mykola.bilokonsky.net/2010/08/flash-css-and-embedded-fonts/